# PysimpleGUI - simple animation

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Thank you for reading this.

I'm working on a simple animation that is based on one of two examples from the PysimpleGUI cookbook. The attached code, of course, it is not doing anything. I've looked through many examples trying to figure out how to update the canvas but without success.

My first attempt was based on the sine wave plot example. I have an endless while loop and a display function. The display on the graph area shows the first iteration through the loop but is never updated after that.

The display function contains:

`graph.DrawCircle((i,j)`, `5`, `line_color='black'`, etc

A second related question, should I be using the canvas or the graph method (as in the sine wave plot example), or doesn't it matter?

I don't want to overwhelm the reader with too much code. If I can get the following to work then I may have a good chance with the real code.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

layout = [      
    [sg.Canvas(size=(100, 100), background_color='red', key= 'canvas')],      
    [sg.T('Change circle color to:'), sg.Button('Red'), sg.Button('Blue')]      
    ]

window = sg.Window('Canvas test')      
window.Layout(layout)      
window.Finalize()

canvas = window.FindElement('canvas')      
cir = canvas.TKCanvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100)

while True:      
    event, values = window.Read()
    '''
    if event is None:      
        break      
    if event == 'Blue':      
        canvas.TKCanvas.itemconfig(cir, fill="Blue")      
    elif event == 'Red':      
        canvas.TKCanvas.itemconfig(cir, fill="Red")

    '''

# this is the part that I need to sort out

    for i in range(10):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            canvas.TKCanvas.itemconfig(cir, fill="Blue")

        else:
            canvas.TKCanvas.itemconfig(cir, fill="Red")

        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer and that is, window.Read(timeout = 0).

Comment: Instead of doing a time.sleep(1) it is better instead to write  window.Read(timeout=1000).   This will cause your delay to happen inside of the GUI thus making your GUI more responsive and still delaying the right amount of time.

Comment: Thank you. timeout = 1000 gives erratic results in this instance. This was just some simple code to illustrate the problem. The code that I finally got working is Conway's game of life.

Comment: Rather than using the Canvas Element and using tkinter calls to draw circles, it would be easier and cleaner to use a Graph Element and then calling the Graph's DrawCircle method.  This way you don't have any direct tkinter interaction and you've achieved the same result on the screen.

Comment: Thank you MikeyB, that's what I used in my Conway's game of life code.

Comment: From the documentation: "**You shouldn't use a timeout of zero unless you're a realtime application and you know what you're doing. A zero value will consume 100% of the CPU core your code is running on.**" Emphasis **not** mine.

Answer (score 0):

In order for changes to show up in a window after making changes, you much either call Read or Refresh.  I think all you need to do is down in your bottom loop, add the line:

```
window.Refresh()
```

From the docs at http://www.PySimpleGUI.org:

> Refresh() 
>   Cause changes to the window to be displayed on the screen.
>   Normally not needed unless the changes are immediately required or if
>   it's going to be a while before another call to Read.